# jQuery fade out container but not children

Tags: jquery, element, fadeout

I want to use jQuery to fade out and fadeIn an element with children.

The problem is that when I fadeOut the parent element on hover, the children elements get faded along with it.

How can I fadeIn/fadeOut a container element, but not its children unless i hover over them?

PS: Can't use RGBA, background-color.

Comment: You can't, though you can give the illusion of this through the use of absolute positioning of the 'children'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, per your question, the only answer is: *you can't*. At all. Should you hide the ancestor, the child disappears.

That said, this can be *emulated*, by the use of absolute positioning and imitation of those child elements; though this is pretty expensive and, I'd strongly suggest, should be avoided if at all possible. However, the following seems to satisfy your use-case, given the following HTML (adjust to taste, obviously):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="unwavering">child one</div>
    <div class="unwavering">child two</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
// creating and caching an element here, to avoid having to create
// elements in each iteration of the 'each()' loop, later:
var clone = $('<div />', {
    'class': 'clone'
});

// iterating over each of the child elements you want to keep visible:
$('.unwavering').each(function () {
    // we'll be referencing this node a few times, so we're caching it:
    var current = $(this),
    // we'll need this for positioning:
        currentPosition = current.position(),
    // getting all the computed styles of the current element:
        css = window.getComputedStyle(this, null),
    // getting the cssText (for the inline style):
        styles = css.cssText,
    // cloning the earlier-created element for use:
        currentClone = clone.clone();

    // setting the 'style' attribute to the cssText:
    currentClone.attr('style', styles).css({
        // overriding the following, so the clones are positioned
        // absolutely relative to the page, not their own offset parents:
        'position': 'absolute',
            'top': currentPosition.top,
            'left': currentPosition.left
    })
    // setting the html of the currentClone to that of the current element
    // (note that any duplicated ids will invalidate your HTML, and (probably)
    // break your JavaScript:
    .html(current.html())
    // setting the 'fakeParent' (made up) property:
    .prop('fakeParent', current.parent())
    // appending the clone to the body:
    .appendTo('body')
    // binding event-handlers:
    .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
        // triggering the same event-handlers on the 'fakeParent' element:
        var target = $(this).prop('fakeParent');
        target.trigger(e.type);
    });;
});

// setting up the mouseenter/mouseleave event-handling:
$('.parent').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    // if the event-type (e.type) is 'mouseenter', or otherwise if
    // the event is 'mouseleave' and the related-target is a clone,
    // we add the 'hidden' class (jQuery won't duplicate present-classes);
    // otherwise we remove the 'hidden' class:
    $(this)[(e.type === 'mouseenter') || (e.type === 'mouseleave' && $(e.relatedTarget).is('.clone')) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('hidden');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/knh8Lcrw/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Event.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget).
  - [`Event.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.type).
  - [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
  - [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).